# Dark and light mode not rendering correctly with the `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />` tag

Tags: html, css, media-queries, meta-tags, color-scheme

I am building a personal portfolio website and i want to implement light and dark mode for accessibilty purpose but it is not rendering correctly.

I've followed a tutorial that use the prefers color-scheme media query to match when my system is set to dark or light mode and it works up to this level with the code below

```
@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --main-color: rgb(253, 248, 247);
    --text-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --main-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    --text-color: rgb(253, 248, 247);
  }
}
```

but I want to tell the user agent (browser) to prefer light mode and implement a toggle button to change back to dark mode if the user prefers it. I used the `<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />` but when my page renders, it still renders with the default dark mode it recognise from my device settings and I want it to use light by default irrespective of the device setting.

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing in? Firefox may currently have issues with this feature, for example.

Comment: I have tested with chrome and firefox